# strange behaviour of Eigensystem and Eigenvectors

Tags: functions

consider this:

```
{Last@Eigensystem[{{0.0, 1.0}, {-2.0, -3.0}}], Eigenvectors[{{0.0, 1.0}, {-2.0, -3.0}}]}
(*{{{-0.447214, 0.894427}, {0.707107, -0.707107}}, {{-0.447214,0.894427}, {0.707107, -0.707107}}}*)
```

now  with integer values:

```
{Last@Eigensystem[{{0, 1}, {-2, -3}}], Eigenvectors[{{0, 1}, {-2, -3}}]}
(*{{{-1, 2}, {-1, 1}}, {{-1, 2}, {-1, 1}}}*)
```

We get two different results. I understand that a single eigenvalue can correspond to multiple eigenvectors but at least there should be some consistency in the outputs (whether members are real values or integers).

I have noticed the same behaviour of both functions on 12.0 and 11.3.

Comment: The two results differ only by multiplicative factors.  Eigenvectors are only defined by a direction, not a magnitude, so both are correct.

Comment: @ChrisK I understand that. But what i mean to say is that there should be some consistency in the output result. Why not output the same final result when either members are real or integers?

Comment: @ChrisK thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: @ChrisK to be more specific, those are the unnormalized `Eigenvectors` (& `Eigenvalues`?) which occur when one uses exact values, correct? Using the second input here, one need only to add `//N` to the end of the given set of values to get the output from the first input.